# Tomar el valor del operador para realizar operaciones javascript

Tags: javascript, operador

Estoy empezando a aprender javascript y el caso es que estamos haciendo una calculadora y no se como hacer para que no me concatene los dos números que he de sumar ej:(al sumar 12 y 20 en el alert me aparece 12+20, es decir, el símbolo + no me lo coge como tal)

Os adjunto el código:

```
function cal() {
var numero1 = document.forms["form1"]["num1"].value;
var numero2 = document.forms["form1"]["num2"].value;
var operador = document.forms["form1"]["operador"].value;
num1 = parseInt(numero1);    
num2 = parseInt(numero2);

 if( Number.isInteger(num1) && Number.isInteger(num2)){
alert("Hola, has metido dos numeros"+operador);
if(operador == "+" || operador == "-" || operador == "*" || operador == "/")
   {
   alert("El operador esta bien ahora vamos a ver el resultado de la operación");
       var resultado = "";
       resultado = num1+operador.valueOf+num2 ;
       alert(resultado);
   }     

 }
    else{
        alert("Algo falla, comprueba si lo que has metido son números de verdad");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema está aquí

```
var resultado = '';
```

Tu variable la estás inicializando como un string, por lo que `+` ahora es concatenación en vez de suma.
Cambia la línea a:

```
var resultado = 0;
```

Y obtendrás el resultado que esperas

Comment: Gracias es cierto que la habia inicializado como una string :( pero aun persigue el problema y sigue sin operar con ambos numeros

Answer (score 2):

Debes convertir los valores a sumar a números, de hecho en el momento en que haces la primer condición lo estás haciendo, entonces deberías volverlo a hacer en la suma:

```
resultado = (Number(num1) + operador.valueOf + Number(num2));
alert(resultado);
```

Con eso debería darte.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Pero aun me sigue saliendo lo mismo y sigue haciendo lo mismo estoy por dejarlo de momento jaja

Comment: Entonces lo que te está poniendo problema es el operador.valueOf, no estoy seguro de si una operación se pueda hacer de esa manera, creo que deberías usar un switch, es mas largo pero así si funcionaría